# JavaScript less than or equals (bool <= int)

Tags: javascript, operators, boolean-expression

I am wondering if anyone can explain the behavious of comparison operators when using booleans and integers.

Why do the following statements produce the results they do?

```
false < = 9 // true
false >= 9 // false
```

Thanks

Comment: `false == 0`, `true == 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The representation of `false` in memory is 0. That's why you obtain those results.